# Are filenames case sensitive in VS2017?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2017

I migrated a solution from VS 2010 to VS 2017. When I build the solution, some files are reported to be missing while they're existing in the specified paths. The solution (which is in C#) was compiling in VS 2010 without any problem. The filenames are the same except their cases. I need to know whether file names are case-sensitive in VS 2017 while they were not in VS 2010? If so, how can I revert this feature, or set the option to ignore the file names cases?

Comment: No. Windows is not case sensitive (it's case preserving however), therefore any program running on top of it won't be case sensitive either. There should be some other difference in the file path, or maybe a missing component in VS required for that particular compilation.

Comment: but the error will be removed when i change the case as VS expects. i think i've to note that the drive is not NTFS. it's a linux drive which is mapped by SFTP Net Drive and is available for Windows as well as VS.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a VS issue. The drive has been mapped by SFTP Net Drive. For such virtual drives, in which the original drive is case-sensitive and will be mapped in Windows which is not case-sensitive, there's an option in the last tab, 'Drive', which one should set it. It's:
Handle case-sensitive filenames